# How to log to EventViewer with WINUI?

Tags: logging, winui-3, winui

How am i supposed to Log to the Windows EventViewer in a WinUI3 App? I was not able to find a working example.

Current Situation:

In every .NET Framework app i used `System.Diagnostics.EventLog`

to write more or less useful `eventLog.WriteEntry(e.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error);`

Messages into the 'Application' Log. The WiX Installer takes care of the EventSource creation during the App installation. Now, i tried to do the same with a WINUI3 App. The logging itself is working as expected. However the eventsource creation is not. I was not able to find any information on how to tell visualstudio to create an eventsource during installation, nor am i confident that this is the right way to go.

So, how am i supposed to do logging on winui if i do not want to log to seperate files wehre i do need seperate programs to read them.

I have had a look at the LoggingSession and LoggingChannel solution with samples. But i do not think this kind of log is consumable without extra tools that needs to be downloaded/installed.

Answer (score 0):

Install the [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.extensions.logging) NuGet package and use it like this:

```cs
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog.EventLogLoggerProvider eventLogLoggerProvider = new();
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger logger = eventLogLoggerProvider.CreateLogger("EventLogExample");
logger.LogInformation("This is an information message");
```

Comment: Thanks, Andrew.

Unfortunately i have a different Problem. I mean, i already do this. The problem is: I do not know how to tell the MSIX package publishing process to create an eventsource when installing. I tried to do this by the app itself:

            'if (!EventLog.SourceExists(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name))
            {
                EventLog.CreateEventSource(new EventSourceCreationData(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name, "Application"));
            }'

While this works fine in WPF .NET FW or in debug mode, it does not in winui / .net 8 release build.

Comment: I think you should [open a new question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions).